Convergence of the hypergeometric series on the p-adic norm
Let $p$ be a prime number and let $a,b,c$ be elements of $\mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{Z}_p$ where $c \notin \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$.
How to show that the hypergeometric series
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{a(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)b(b+1)\cdots(b+k-1)}{c(c+1)\cdots(c+k-1)k!}x^k $$
converges with respect to the $p$-adic norm when $|x| < 1$?
I think that since multiples of $p$ appear periodically in $a(a+1)\cdots (a+k-1)$, the growth of the coefficients is likely to be moderate, but I can't prove it rigorously.

Welcome to Math StackExchange. Since this is your first post on this site, I recommend you read how to as a good question and update your post accordingly, as now you haven't shown any context of the problem or your effort on solving it.
